Correct prepositions following "that" in comparison structures

US citizens spent the smallest portion on food among all countries, at 14%, which was about 9% smaller than that by the Japanese.

I chose by here as in "...9% smaller than the portion spent by the Japanese" because that here refers to the portion. However, of also came into my mind as a possibly correct one. So, which should I use? Is using by without spent preceding it incorrect?

I feel that adding "spend" might make it better here: "US citizens spent the smallest portion on food among all countries, at 14%, which was about 9% smaller than that spent by the Japanese."

I agree that adding "spent" (not "spend") makes the text a bit better, but I think it's a complete "non-problem" in the first place. Just say ...which was about 9% less than the Japanese and be done with it. The meaning is unambiguously obvious, and there's no good reason to add unnecessary verbiage. In fact, I'd be perfectly happy with ...9% less than Japan.

portion on food ain't great. Also, US citizens? No. I doubt you mean that.  Consumers in the US spent 14 % of their disposable income on food compared to 9% more [spent by consumers] in Japan. Now, it sounds like economics.

Thanks, @Lambie.  Yes, we should use
consumers in the US and of their disposable income :)
